# CentOS 6 iptables

Tags: centos, iptables

When I am adding this to iptabls it works

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 100 -j DROP
```

But when I try changing the port number to the one i need nothing happens
can anyone help?

Comment: First, can you show the output from `iptables-save`?

Comment: Post your entire iptables config. Until you do, it's all guesses.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you added your rule at the end of the INPUT (-A == APPEND) chain so probably another rule before allows the traffic. Try with something like that:

```
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport ${PORT_VALUE} -j DROP
```